# share local files (audio,video) via local http server in android

Tags: android, http, httpserver

i want to share my local audio and video files inside the phone through a HTTP server by creating a link.and through that link i can access my local file any where on the network.i used this open source project [this](https://code.google.com/p/share-via-http/) but i doesn't share video files i think because of large size.I also tried to use nano httpd server but it has same issue too.Can any one tell me any other open source server as i cant be able to find one

Comment: Hi, I am looking for same solution. Were you able to do it?
It would be great if you can help.

Answer (score 0):

Jetty is the most popular one. http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/